# WPGlobus : Set second language as a default for some page

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have used WPGlobus for language translation. It's working well. I have used two language English and Spanish. English is the first language. Now I need to add Spanish is the first language for some of my pages not for all pages. How can I do that?

Thanks!

```
if ( class_exists( 'WPGlobus' ) ) {
    $flag = WPGlobus::Config()->flags_url . WPGlobus::Config()->flag[ WPGlobus::Config()->language ];
    //echo '<img src="' . $flag . '" /> ';
    echo '<li class="unactive"> ' . WPGlobus::Config()->en_language_name[ WPGlobus::Config()->language ]. '</li>';
    foreach( WPGlobus::Config()->enabled_languages as $lang ) {
        if ( $lang == WPGlobus::Config()->language ) {
            continue;
        }
        $flag = WPGlobus::Config()->flags_url . WPGlobus::Config()->flag[ $lang ];
        echo '<li class="active language" ><a href="' . WPGlobus_Utils::localize_current_url( $lang ). '">';
        echo  WPGlobus::Config()->en_language_name[ $lang ];
        echo '</a></li>';

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to have some pages to have only Spanish content, with no English.

WPGlobus always displays the primary language content. If you do not have a Spanish translation, it will show English.

So, you can, for example, enter the Spanish text into the English tab - and that page will always be in Spanish.

---

Also, there is a premium add-on called [WPGlobus Plus](https://wpglobus.com/product/wpglobus-plus/), which allows specifying which translation is "published" and which is "draft".